# Angularjs:-How to call controller actions with the help of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

Hi I am a newbie on angularjs.

I wanted to implement a code where when I click on a button,I should be able to make an api call and display data inside the HTML.

Now I have implemented a directive and the HTML is generated,but however when I click on favicon or reminder,It is not working.

The following is implemented in the controller called usercontroller(It has a lot of other functionalities).However I am not very sure how to call the controller,only for specifically favicon.

The below is the directive I have written:-

```
'use strict';
var pageno=1;

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
}

//Directive that returns an element which adds buttons on click which show an alert on click.Here we can put
woi.directive("yes",['userAPI','$rootScope', function(userAPI,$rootScope){

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<button ng-click='str()' addbuttons>please click for Top Rated</button>"



//Directive for adding buttons on click that show an alert on click
woi.directive("addbuttons",['$rootScope','userAPI','$compile','$filter', function($rootScope,userAPI,$compile,$filter,){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){
         //   var pageno=1;
            scope.count++;
            var pageno=1;
            pageno++;
            scope.pageNo=pageno;
            //var abc= scope.loadRated(pageno);
            userAPI.topRated({userid: $rootScope.getUser().userid,pageno:pageno}, function (r, $scope, div){
                if(!$rootScope.device.isMobile && !$rootScope.device.isTablet && !$rootScope.device.isTouch ) {
                    var topRatedList = r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist;
                    console.log(r)


                    var str='';
                    if(r !=null && r.gettopratedhomepage!=null && r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist!=null)
                        if(r.gettopratedhomepage.topratedprogrammelist.length>0){

                            for(var i=0;i<topRatedList.length;i++)
                            {
                                // str+="topRatedList[i].actualname";

                                var programNameEncode=$filter('encodeUrl')(topRatedList[i].programmename);  // | encodeUrl;    topRatedList[i].programmename;
                                var program=topRatedList[i].programmename;
                                var channelId=topRatedList[i].channelid;
                                var programId=topRatedList[i].programmeid;
                                var channel=topRatedList[i].channeldisplayname;
                                var channelNameEncode=$filter('encodeUrl')(topRatedList[i].channeldisplayname)       //| encodeUrl;
                                //   var startTime=topRatedList[i].starttime;
                                var favourite=topRatedList[i].isfavorite;
                                var reminder=topRatedList[i].isreminder;
                                var watchlist=topRatedList[i].iswatchlist;
                                var duration=topRatedList[i].duration;
                                var imageFile=topRatedList[i].imagefilepath;
                                var startTime = $filter('featuredVideoTime')(topRatedList[i].starttime) ;             // featured video time
                                var duration= topRatedList[i].duration;
                                var isReco=topRatedList[i].isrecommended;         // This is for reco

                                var genre=topRatedList[i].channelgenre;
                                var imagefilepath=topRatedList[i].imagefilepath;
                                var logo= topRatedList[i].logofileurl;

                                var p={

                                    $$hashKey: "10Z",
                                    actualname: "program",
                                    channeldisplayname: "channel",
                                    channelgenre: "genre",
                                    channelid: "channelId",
                                    channellogo: "logo",
                                    channelname: "channel",
                                    channelweburl: null,
                                    contextualtext: "Rated for You",
                                    endtime: "2014-10-07T12:15:00",
                                    genre: "genre",
                                    imagefilepath: "imagefilepath",
                                    ischeckin: "0",
                                    isfavorite: "0",
                                    isrecommended: "0",
                                    isreminder: "0",
                                    iswatchlist: "0",
                                    isyoutube: topRatedList[i].isyoutube,
                                    keywords: null,
                                    languagename: "English",
                                    //    logofileurl: logo,
                                    programmeduration: "50",
                                    programmeid: "",
                                    programmename: "New Tricks",
                                    reminderid: "0",
                                    rownumber: "2",
                                    serialno: "0",
                                    starttime: "2014-10-07T11:25:00",
                                    synopsis: "To put her flagging police career back on track, Sandra Pullman hires three old veterans to lend a helping hand.",
                                    timestring: "11:25 AM, Tomorrow",
                                    totalcheckincount: "0",
                                    totalprogramfavcount: "13",
                                    totalremindercount: "34"

                                }


                                str+=" <div class='item' style='display: block;' >" ;
                                str+="<div class=\"thumb\">";
                                //     str+="<div ng-show=\""+isReco=='1'+"\" class=\"favorite-ribbon\"></div>";
                                str+="<div class=\"player\"></div>";
                                str+="<div class='image' >";
                                str+="<img src='"+imageFile+"' style='width:100%;height:100%;'/>";
                                str+="<a ng-click=\'playVideo("+program+"\,$event)' ng-show='hasVideo()' class='play' style='cursor:pointer'></a>";

                                str+="<a ng-href=\"#!/program/"+programNameEncode+"\"  ng-show=\"!hasVideo()\" class=\"noPlay\" style='position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;' ng-click=\"EncodeUrlWithDash("+program+",$event,'programme',"+channelId+","+programId+","+startTime+")\"></a></div>";

                                str+="<span class='time' ng-show='duration'>\""+duration+"\"</span>";

                                str+="<div class='user-actions' ng-controller='UserController'>";

                                str+="<a live-tooltip='Add to Favorite'  ng-click='toggleFavorite("+topRatedList+", $event)'  class='btn btn-small btn-purple-blue' ng-class=\""+{active:favourite == '1'}+"\">";
                                str+="<i class='icon-favorite'></i></a>";

                                str+="<a live-tooltip='Reminder Alerts'  ng-click='toggleReminder("+topRatedList+", $event)'  class='btn btn-small btn-purple-blue' ng-class=\""+{active:reminder == '1'}+"\">";
                                str+="<i class='icon-reminder'></i></a>";

                                str+="<a live-tooltip='Add to Watchlist' ng-click='addToWatchlist(p, $event)'  class='btn btn-small btn-purple-blue' ng-class=\""+{active:watchlist == '1'}+"\">";
                                str+="<i class='icon-watchlist'></i></a></div>";  //end of user controller div

                                str+="</div>";    // end of thumb div

                                str+="<div class='text-wrapper'>";
                                str+="<h2 multiline-overflow><a title='"+program+"' href='#!/program/"+programNameEncode+"' ng-click=\""+"EncodeUrlWithDash(\""+program+"\",$event,'programme',\""+channelId+"\",\""+programId+"\",\""+startTime+"\")"+"/ >"+program+"</a></h2>";

                                str+="<p class='infoChannel' live-tooltip-single-line= '"+channel+"'><a href='#!/channel/"+channelNameEncode+"' ng-click=\""+"EncodeUrlWithDash(\""+channel+"\",$event,'channel',\""+channelId+"\",\""+programId+"\")"+"/ >"+channel+"</a></p>";
                                str+="<p class='info'>"+startTime+"</p>";

                                str+="</div></div>";  //end of the main div

                                //EXTRA LINE
                                //          str+=" <div class='item' ng-repeat='topRatedList[i] in programs.rated' home-tab-item watchable='topRatedList[i]' ></div>" ;

                                //          angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).append($compile(str)(scope));

                            }         // For loop end here..Declaration

                        }
                        else{

                            str="No data found";
                        }

                    angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).append($compile(str)(scope));



                    // The above code is required to append data into the division(loadrated)..

                }
            });

        });
    };
}]);
```

I have created a string and am creating the HTML for the programs to be generated.

Can someone please help me with this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call controller's action from the directive when you click the button after display specific message, you can set the action and message as parameters in directive. try this

```
'use strict';

angular.module('directives')
    .directive("MyButton", function(){
        return{
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            link :function(scope, element, atts){
                    var buttonText = "<button class='btn btn-primary'>click</button>";
                    element.html(buttonText);
                    element.on("click", function(){
                        var result = confirm(atts.message);
                        if(result)
                        {
                            scope.$apply(atts.action);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    });
```

and then you can set the parameters in the directive this way

```
<my-button message="Are you sure?" action="delete"></my-button>
```

Comment: @safaa-elgendi..Thanks for the info..However I want to make a api call with the help of a parameter and get the result when I click on the button.Can we implement this